# JBOSS configuration error

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm trying to add the following `security-domain` in the JBOSS AS7 `standalone.xml`

```
<security-domain name="form-authentication" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Database" flag="sufficient">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery">select password from Users_Authentication where username=?</module-option>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery">select rolename, 'Roles' from Users_Roles where username=?</module-option>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

But I'm having the following error: `Missing required attribute(s): value` (pointing to the second module-option). I've already tried to put `value=""`, but a new error appears pointing to the closing tag `</module-option>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following `principalQuery` and `rolesQuery` `module-option` descriptors. Actually you need to put the "select .... " in the values part.

```
<module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from Users_Authentication where username=?"/>
<module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select rolename, 'Roles' from Users_Roles where username=?"/>
```